# Find the gcd of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Use the division algorithm to the find the gcd of $f(x)= 2x^4 + 5x^3 -5x -2$ and $g(x)= 2x^3 -3x^2 -2x$ in $\mathbb Q[x]$.

I used long division and found the following

$$f(x) = (x+4)g(x) + \left( 14x^2 + 3x -2 \right)$$

So I have found the polynomials $q(x)$ and $r(x)$ such that $$f(x) = q(x)g(x) + r(x)$$ where $\deg [r(x)] < deg[g(x)]$.

This is where I am stuck. How do I go about finding the GCD of $f$ and $g$? I know that it must be some monic ploynomial $d(x)$

Comment: You now have to keep going and find the remainder when $g(x)$ is divided by $14x^2+3x-2$.  Continue until the remainder is zero, then the last nonzero remainder is the gcd.  Now, divide by the coefficient of the leading term to make it monic.

Comment: @MichaelBurr  thank you! So I simply continue doing long division with $g(x)$ and $r(x)$?

Comment: @MichaelBurr . If I simply factorize $g$ and $r$, I see that the smallest common factor they have, is $(2x +1)$ so the monic gcd of $f$ and $g$ will be the "monic version" of $(2x+1)$, which is simply $d(x) = x + \frac{1}{2}$? :)

Comment: I'm not checking your work for correctness, but the description that you're giving in words seems to be the right steps.

Answer (score 1):

They key property is that if $f=gq+r$, then $$\tag{1}\gcd(f,g)=\gcd(g,r).$$

So, you already found that 
$$
f(x) = (x+4)g(x) + \left( 14x^2 + 3x -2 \right).
$$
Now
$$
g(x)=\left(\frac17\,x-\frac{12}{49}\right)(14x^2+3x-2)+\left(-\frac{48}{49}x-\frac{24}{49}\right).
$$
And
$$
14x^2+3x-2=\left(-\frac{343}{24}x+\frac{49}{12}\right)\left(-\frac{48}{49}x-\frac{24}{49}\right).
$$
Then, using property $(1)$, 
$$
\gcd(f,g)=\gcd(g,14x^2+3x-2)=\gcd\left(14x^2+3x-2,-\frac{48}{49}x-\frac{24}{49}\right)=-\frac{48}{49}x-\frac{24}{49}
$$
(the last equality because $-\frac{48}{49}x-\frac{24}{49}$ is a factor of $14x^2+3x-2$). To get the monic version, we multiply by $-49/48$, to get
$$
\gcd(f,g)=x+\frac12.
$$